# Capture text between optional tokens

Tags: .net, regex

Currently I have the following regex:

```
!include <(.*)>
```

And given the following input:

```
## Heading
Some text

!include <mykey>

## Heading 2
Some more text

!include <mykey2>
More text
```

I get `!include <mykey>` matched with capture `mykey` and `!include <mykey2>` matched with capture `mykey2`, which is exactly what I want.

But now I want the `<>` tokens to be optional, so given the following input:

```
## Heading
Some text

!include mykey

## Heading 2
Some more text

!include <mykey2>
More text
```

I want to get the same captures.
I have tried the following:

```
!include <?([^<>]*)>?$
```

but it doesn't work, any help would be appreciated.

### Update1

I have tried @pedro-lobito answer but I am getting an extra `>` in the group $1.
Here is the code I am running:

```
var includeRegex = new Regex("!include\\s+<?(.+?)>?$",
                RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.Multiline);
var input = @"
## Heading
Some text
!include <mykey>
## Heading 2
Some more text
";
var match = includeRegex.Match(input);
Console.WriteLine(match.Groups[1].Value); // Outputs mykey>, it should be mykey
```

Comment: `!include <?.*>?` or `!include (<.*>|[^<>]+)`

Comment: Regex matches both string http://regexr.com/3fn6d

Comment: @zerkms those do not capture a group

Comment: @Hakunamatata no group capture

Comment: @JohnSimons is it a problem for you to put extra parentheses really? SO is to help solving your problems, not to do whole job for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `?` to make the `<>` optional

```
!include\s<?(.*?)>?$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/jmYL4S/3)

Comment: But this capture would include `<>`, I want to exclude those

Comment: I tried the updated answer but the group $1 is getting an extra `>`. I will update the question with the c# code I have tried.

Comment: You want group 1 to match everything except < and >, so change .*? for [^<>]*?